# How to do partial read and calculate md5sum of a large file in RUST?

Tags: rust, md5

I'm writing a program to calculate md5sum of files. The core codes is :

```
use md5;
use std::fs::File;

fn func(file_path: &str) {
    let mut f = File::open(file_path).unwrap();
    let mut contents = Vec::<u8>::new();
    f.read_to_end(&mut contents).unwrap();
    let digest = md5::compute(&contents.as_slice());
    println!("{:x}\t{}", digest, file_path);
}
```

This function work well with moderate-size files. But it will raise a segmentation fault when calculating a large file, generate a core dump file more than 22G. How to do partial read and calculate the md5sum separately and then gather them into a final result?

Comment: You can write into a context incrementally. Review the docs at https://docs.rs/md5/latest/md5/struct.Context.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `BufReader` to read the file in chunks:

```rs
let f = File::open(file_path).unwrap();
// Find the length of the file
let len = f.metadata().unwrap().len();
// Decide on a reasonable buffer size (1MB in this case, fastest will depend on hardware)
let buf_len = len.min(1_000_000) as usize;
let mut buf = BufReader::with_capacity(buf_len, f);
let mut context = md5::Context::new();
loop {
    // Get a chunk of the file
    let part = buf.fill_buf().unwrap();
    // If that chunk was empty, the reader has reached EOF
    if part.is_empty() {
        break;
    }
    // Add chunk to the md5
    context.consume(part);
    // Tell the buffer that the chunk is consumed
    let part_len = part.len();
    buf.consume(part_len);
}
let digest = context.compute();
println!("{:x}\t{}", digest, file_path);
```

I'm not sure if this is going to help, though. I would expect yours to have a memory allocation error, so segmentation fault is unexpected.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot. I think `BufReader` is even faster than `File::read()`. (My test result shows that is about 3%~5% faster)